# How to separate executable calls as different functions in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, gnome-terminal

This is what I would like to achieve.

```
#!/bin/bash

function startBasics()
{
    gnome-terminal -e "sth" &
    gnome-terminal --tab -e "sth_else" &
}

function doOneThing()
{
    gnome-terminal --working-directory=/myDir1/build/ -e './myExecutable1' &
}

function doAnotherThing()
{
    gnome-terminal --working-directory=/myDir2/build/ -e './myExecutable2' &
}

$(startBasics)
$(doOneThing)
$(doAnotherThing)
```

However, after `startBasics` completes, other functions do not execute at all. So I put them all in the same place inside `startBasics` and tried again and this seems to work properly.

So why did the above code not work? And what is the proper way to write separate functions?

Answer (score 1):

Your:

```
$(startBasics)
```

doesn't make sense and is the cause of your problem. That's command substitution. `$(cmd)` expands to the output of `cmd` (with trailing newlines removed and subject to split+glob as you didn't quote it). You're asking the shell to make up a command out of the output of `startBasics`.

What that means is that the shell needs to read the output of `startBasics` until end-of-file to expand it. That expansion here will be taken as a command to execute which makes little sense.

To achieve command substitution, the shell starts `startBasics` with its stdout redirected to a pipe, and reads from the other end of the pipe. All of the `gnome-terminal` processes will inherit that stdout.

The shell will only see eof at the other end of the pipe when all file descriptors open to the writing end (in all processes) have been closed. That is likely only going to happen when all the `gnome-terminals` started by `startBasics` have terminated.

Here, you want:

```
#!/bin/sh -

startBasics() {
    gnome-terminal -e "sth" &
    gnome-terminal --tab -e "sth_else" &
}
doOneThing() {
    gnome-terminal --working-directory=/myDir1/build/ -e './myExecutable1' &
}
doAnoterThing() {
    gnome-terminal --working-directory=/myDir2/build/ -e './myExecutable2' &
}

startBasics
doOneThing
doAnoterThing

wait # if you'd rather wait for all those processes to finish
     # before exiting.
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is amazing. I am a newbie in shell-scripting, can you recommend a good reading on this?

Comment: @ceroloy, I can't really help much as I learnt myself about shells decades ago, so wouldn't know what good resources are available now. For `bash` (the GNU  shell) specifically, Greg's Wiki (start maybe with http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) is a very good resource.

Answer (score 0):

Your `&` starts the command in the background. So the complaint

> after startBasics completes other functions do not execute at all.

is probably due to the phenomenon that these other programs are running *and completing* before `startBasics` completes.

Further, it is not necessary to encapsulate the command within `$( ... )`. Simply invoking the function *as a command* will work:

```
startBasics
doOneThing
doAnoterThing
```

But somehow I suspect that what you want to do is to run these commands *within* one terminal, one after the other. In this case, you would do something like:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/myDir2/build/ -x /bin/sh -c 'sthe; sthelse; ./myExecutable1; ./myExecutable2'
```

See https://superuser.com/questions/198015/open-gnome-terminal-programmatically-and-execute-commands-after-bashrc-was-execu